# What is the Grammatical reason of using linking verb + past participle in a sentence?

Tags: linking-verbs

I found this sentence in a blog post and the poster has used a linking verb followed by a past participle verb form in a sentence, which gives me a bit of confusing. Here is the sentence below:

> In hospital, she *felt stripped* of all her dignity.

The part I don't understand here is the usage of the past participle verb after the verb 'felt'. For me this sentence as like a passive form, which may be like *"In hospital, she was stripped (by someone)..."*.

Can anyone do me the grammatical explanation of this, please?

Comment: Compare 'In hospital, she felt wretched'.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> "Stripped" is not a verb in your example; it's an adjective functioning as a subjective predicative complement. "Stripped of all her dignity" is an adjective phrase with "stripped" as head and the past participle, "of all her dignity" as its complement. – [BillJ](https://english.stackexchange.com/users/141248/billj)

Comment: In hospital, she felt stripped of all her dignity. = In hospital, she felt *[as if she had been]* stripped of all her dignity.